# php mail function with customizes from value

Tags: php, email

Why does this send emails?

```
 $from_admin = $_POST[EMAIL]; 
 $message_admin = 'some html...';
 mail($to_admin,"subject",$message_admin,"FROM:$from_admin");
```

This email looks like it came from my gmail account.

While this doesn't send the email.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To:' . $to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Registration <register@myserver.org>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When I contacted my hosting support, they said that I need to do SMTP authentication.  But, then why does the first mail function work?  I would be ok if its not actually using that server, but people can reply the the html email and still reach the correct account.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Use http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: the mail() page in the manual should start with "don't use this function"

Comment: $message and $subject are tested, that is you're sure that the mail function doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: You should Google mail() header injection.

Comment: @Dagon What do you suggest to use instead?

Comment: smoke signals! - no seriously swiftmailer or [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), or even the pear mail lib.

Comment: I've never had something like this before. I think you should either check your header clarity or using mailing libraries for PHP. I use `mail()` too except those moments that SMTP is not configured!